# Why doesn't AnimatePresence work in the TypeScript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, framer-motion

Help me sort out the problem on which I have been sitting for 4 days.
I have a big project written in TC with a lot of modal windows. I need to style the smooth opening and closing of a modal using framer-motion.
I follow the manuals of the library did it. But the window closing animation doesn't work. Help solve the problem please.
I will be very grateful for the help.
Here is the modal window component which is then reused in many places in the project :

```
import {
  FC,
  PropsWithChildren,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ModalBody from './ModalBody';
import ModalContext, { ModalContextValue } from './ModalContext';
import ModalFooter from './ModalFooter';
import ModalHeader from './ModalHeader';
import { motion, AnimatePresence, MotionProps } from 'framer-motion';

const dropIn = {
  hidden: {
    y: '-100vh',
    opacity: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    y: '0',
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      duration: 1,
      type: 'spring',
      damping: 15,
      stiffness: 200,
    },
  },
  exit: {
    y: '100vh',
    opacity: 0,
  },
};

export interface ModalProps extends PropsWithChildren {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  onOpen?: () => void;
  width?: string;
}

const Modal: FC<ModalProps & MotionProps> = (props) => {
  const { isOpen, onClose, onOpen, children, width } = props;
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(isOpen);
  const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const contextValue = useMemo<ModalContextValue>(() => {
    return {
      handleClose: onClose,
    };
  }, [onClose]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsModalOpen(isOpen);
  }, [isOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isModalOpen) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      modalRef.current?.focus();
      onOpen?.();
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }
  }, [isModalOpen]);

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
    onClose?.();
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
      closeModal();
    }
  };

  if (!isModalOpen) return null;
  console.log(AnimatePresence);

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <ModalContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto">
        <AnimatePresence onExitComplete={() => closeModal()}>
          <motion.div
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 1 }}
            ref={modalRef}
            className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen p-6"
            tabIndex={-1}
            role="dialog"
            aria-modal="true"
            aria-labelledby="modal-title"
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          >
            <div
              className="fixed inset-0"
              aria-hidden="true"
              onClick={closeModal}
            >
              <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
            </div>

            <motion.div
              variants={dropIn}
              initial={dropIn.hidden}
              animate={dropIn.visible}
              exit={dropIn.exit}
              className={`
            bg-iit-gray text-white rounded-md text-left overflow-hidden
            shadow-xl transform  sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full
            md:max-w-3xl h-full max-h-[90vh] ${width}`}
              role="document"
            >
              {children}
            </motion.div>
          </motion.div>
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </ModalContext.Provider>,

    document.body,
  );
};

Modal.displayName = 'Modal';

export default Object.assign(Modal, {
  Header: ModalHeader,
  Body: ModalBody,
  Footer: ModalFooter,
});
```

I tried different installation options for AnimatePresence. Outside the container and also inside it. There was also an attempt to install AnimatePresence directly in the place where the modal window is rendered (that is, where the Modal component is called), but this did not bring the desired result.
I also deleted the createPortal and generally half of the code in the Modal component. The animation only works on opening the window, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

1.)
Try to add a `key` prop to your `motion.div`. Framer needs a key prop on direct descendants of `AnimatePresence` in order to track when the div exits.

```
<AnimatePresence>
  <motion.div 
   key="uniquekeyforthisdiv"
   {...otherProps}>
  </motion.div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

More info here on key prop here : https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/

2.) Edited to address your comment:

`if (!isModalOpen) return null;`

This line is making it so that the component is returning `null` rather than the `AnimatePresence` wrapped component. So the component disappears before `AnimatePresence` can exit itself.
Remove this line and update your `AnimatePresence` return statement to something similar as follows:

```
<AnimatePresence>
  { isModalOpen && 
  <motion.div key="uniquekeyforthisdiv"  {...otherProps}.>
   ...
  </motion.div>
  }
</AnimatePresence>
```

The check for the modal open should be inside `AnimatePresence` so `AnimatePresence` can detect its children disappearing and animate it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I already tried it. I don't know where to get the value of this key. I wrote a random name and it didn't work.((

Comment: @IhorKolontaievskiy I've updated my answer, I hope this can help you. The key is arbitrary and something you decide. It is just there as a unique identifier for the motion.div children of AnimatePresence.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me with this problem. I did as you said and the animation still does not work when unmounted :( It seems to me that the problem lies somewhere in the project. Because I tried to do everything the same on the test version and everything works there. This is a large project assembled using NX , maybe somewhere you need to create a configuration file?